# Rails 4 Form Syntax for Stripe Bank Token -

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm building a marketplace and have a form to collect bank account details from sellers so we can transfer payments.

One of the stripe parameters is the sellers name, which is an input on the form. When I submit the form, the controller reads the name only if it is stored in the database already (i.e. if I manually enter name in db, then run form). If a name doesn't already exist, it gives me an error saying I need to enter a name to create the stripe token.

How do I change the form/method such that the name is available for stripe when the user hits submit?

Here is my update method: the error is in the line with **:name => current_user.bankaccname**. This is an input in the form pasted below.

```
def update

    Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
      token = params[:stripeToken]

      recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
        :name => current_user.bankaccname,
        :type => "individual",
        :bank_account => token
        )

      current_user.recipient = recipient.id
      current_user.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_url, notice: 'Your account was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```

my form:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_path, html: { method: :put } do |f| %>
     <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %><i> (as it appears in your bank account)</i>
      <%= f.text_field :bankaccname, class:"form-control" %>
     </div>

 <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :country %>
      <%= text_field_tag :country, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "country", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :routing_number %>
      <%= text_field_tag :routing_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "routingNumber", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :account_number %>
      <%= text_field_tag :account_number, nil, { :name => nil, :'data-stripe' => "accountNumber", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
     </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: so where iz the problem.? u can manually enter bankaccname in the form if not present?, then submit.

Comment: I meant that if I go to the console and input the bank account name in the user model, then submit the form, it works. So stripe reads name from the db but not via the form. Is there a way I can save the name in db and then call stripe function?

Comment: u can write :name => current_user.bankaccname || user_params["bankaccname"]

Comment: is current_user and @user is same.?

Comment: yes. so I don't need to specify current_user? Also, I'm passing the bank account number and routing number tdirectly to stripe without storing it. Is there a way to call those variables? I want to display current account data above the form.

Comment: for that i think there should be a API call to stripe, to get bank account info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this, it is more optimized, it makes only one  call to db (i guess).
and it will solve your above problem too.

```
def update
    @user.attributes = user_params
    Stripe.api_key = ENV["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
      token = params[:stripeToken]

      recipient = Stripe::Recipient.create(
        :name => @user.bankaccname,
        :type => "individual",
        :bank_account => token
        )

     @user.recipient = recipient.id
     respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_user_url, notice: 'Your account was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end
```