# Rails 4 - Form input into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a seller profile on a marketplace app. I get a can't find user error.

I'm passing the ID in the route so I'm not sure why it's not reading it.

route:

```
get '/users/:id/sellerprofile' => 'users#sellerprofile', as:'sellerprofile'
```

users_controller method: the error is in the user_params method - "param not found: user"

```
  def sellerprofile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      end
    end
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:bankaccname, :profileimage, :profilestory)
  end
```

sellerprofile.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_path, html: { method: :put, :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :your_story %><i> (required)</i>
    <%= f.text_area :profilestory, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :profile_image %><i> (required)</i>
    <%= f.file_field :profileimage, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-primary" %>
   </div>

 <% end %>
```

Here is the server error:

```
Processing by UsersController#sellerprofile as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"71"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT
1  [["id", "71"]]
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 71 ORDER
 BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT
1  [["id", 71]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 6ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: user):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:54:in `user_params'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:32:in `block in sellerprofile'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:31:in `sellerprofile'
```

Comment: can you add your params from rails server. ?

Comment: Sorry I just stepped out. Does the code look right? Maybe I just need a server restart.

Comment: are you sending user params in def sellerprofilere , if not how could you use it in @user.update(user_params)

Comment: I have the two profile fields in def user_params. So am I not updating user_params? What should I ch ange that to? user.update_attrbutes?

Comment: your error says "param not found: user" means its not finding user in params.require(:user), i guessed.

Comment: Just added the server logs. looks like the id is being passed.

Comment: you have no any params other than "id", then y u are updating user.?

Comment: Looks like I'm missing some basic concepts here. I want to take the two fields in my form and save it into the user model. I have those fields as params. What do I put in my controller to input these fields?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong way, if you have following routes

```
match "/users/:id/sellerprofile", to: "users#sellerprofile", via: [:get, :put], as: :sellerprofile
```

and your form is in sellerprofile.html.erb, then your code is correct except update user part.

```
def sellerprofile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if params[:user]
      respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update(user_params)
           format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your profile was successfully updated.' }
        else
          format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        end
      end
    end
end

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:bankaccname, :profileimage, :profilestory)
end
```

your form (sellerprofile.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for @user, url: sellerprofile_path(@user), method: :put, html: { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :your_story %><i> (required)</i>
    <%= f.text_area :profilestory, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :profile_image %><i> (required)</i>
    <%= f.file_field :profileimage, class:"form-control" %>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit class:"btn btn-primary" %>
   </div>

 <% end %>
```

Comment: yesterday, you gave me this code for another user related form http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629910/rails-4-form-syntax-for-stripe-bank-token - how do I use the above update code?

Comment: can you check your rails server, whether it is submitting to correct path, with all params and with :put method.

Comment: Nothing is being submitted. Is there an issue with the form?

Comment: in the method, you have if params[:user]. when i remove that, i get the same error of user not found. it's still not reading the user. you've spent a lot of time on this. thank you! i'll try to figure this out.